# Find next Div Class name after parent div class name, using php/dom/xpath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have a known Div Class name, and I can retrieve the inner html code all good, but how would I retrieve the next Div Class name (not inner from the known Div Class) using php, dom document and xpath?
For example with the code below, if I know the Div class "mobile-container mobile-filter-container", how would I return "mobile-container mobile-cart-content-container"?

```
<div class="mobile-container mobile-filter-container">
  <div class="mobile-wrapper-header"></div>
  <div class="mobile-filter-wrapper"></div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-container mobile-cart-content-container">
  <div class="mobile-wrapper-header">
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add how you actually get the first div and what you have tried to get the second one?

Comment: With the first div class, for my case I know it's name already and I get it's contents by the included function which works ( I am passing the dom document as a function parameter), but I don't know the name of the next and I'm having a difficult time trying to understand how to get it thanks: function Bn($dom){
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$classname = "knownClassname";
$div = $xpath->query("//div[@id='" . $classname . "']");
$div = $div->item(0);
$bn = $dom->saveHtml($div);
return $bn;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should get you close enough to what you need:

```
$data = <<<DATA
<html>
 <div class="mobile-container mobile-filter-container">
  <div class="mobile-wrapper-header"></div>
  <div class="mobile-filter-wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="mobile-container mobile-cart-content-container">
  <div class="mobile-wrapper-header"></div>
    <div class="mobile-filter-wrapper"></div>
</div>     
<div class="unwanted">
  <div class="mobile-wrapper-header"></div>
    <div class="mobile-filter-wrapper"></div>
</div>    
</html>
DATA;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="mobile-container mobile-filter-container"]/following-sibling::div[1]/@class');
echo $elements[0]->nodeValue;
```

Output:

```
mobile-container mobile-cart-content-container
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, exactly what I was looking for :)